# D3 Geopath from geojson after filtering by geoContains

Tags: d3.js

Bit of background. I have a geojson of water systems which a user can search by inputting their address. (the address search returns gps coordinates for the address and I use a d3.geoContains to return the associated system).

After I return the system from the master geojson, I then use the returned data to populate some text fields (this works). I also want to draw the system boundary on pre-rendered map (this does not work).

I'm sure I'm making some basic mistake, but I've been looking at this too long for me to figure it out.

The relevant code looks like this:

```
d3.json("/PublicWaterSupply2018_04.geojson").then(function(data) {

console.log(data)

data.features.forEach(function(d) {
        console.log('running check');   

        if ( d3.geoContains(d, place) == true ) { console.log(d.properties.NAME)

               console.log(d) // DOES return geometry and properties of filtered system.

                console.log('drawing stuff')

// this is the bit that does not work (note the circle is there to test the data bind)

               legend.selectAll("blebs")
               .data(d)
               .enter()
               .append("path")
               .attr("d", path)
               .attr("fill", "red");

               legend.selectAll("bleb")
               .data(d)
               .enter()
               .append("circle")
               .attr('cx', 150)
               .attr('cy', 150)
               .attr('r', 5)
               .attr("fill", "blue");


//everything past here works:

               legend
               .append("circle")
               .attr('cx', 150)
               .attr('cy', 150)
               .attr('r', 10)
               .attr("fill", "black");

            d3.select("#system").text(d.properties.NAME);
            d3.select("#type").text(d.properties.OWNERSHIP);
            d3.select("#county").text(d.properties.CNTY_NAME);
            d3.select("#link").text(d.properties.PWS_ID );
        };

        });


    });
```

Comment: .data() requires an array - you are passing a geojson object, try `.data([d])`

Comment: awesome, thanks. I knew it was something simple like that, but like I said, too many hours staring at it.